# make a DateTime object for now and calculate 1 hour from now php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have some PHP code:

```
$time = new DateTime();
$sub = new DateInterval('P1H');
echo $time->sub($sub);
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 
'DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (P1H)' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\dailylog\test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\dailylog\test.php(4): DateInterval->__construct('P1H') 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dailylog\test.php on line 4
```

What am I doing wrong? How could I get this to work?

EDIT: I guess I'll actually be pulling the time entered from the database and checking if has been + 1 hour. So, sorry for not being clear.

EDIT #2: Since I cant answer my own question...here's what I was going to say:

I did a test on my own and it works perfect! Here's the code:

```
try {
    $time = new DateTime();
    $add = new DateInterval('PT1H');
    $test = new DateTime();
    $ing = new DateInterval('PT1H');

    $time->add($add);
    $test->add($ing);

    if ($time->format('g:i a') == $test->format('g:i a')) {
        echo 'Match';
    }
     else {
        echo 'No match';
    }
}
 catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Try `$sub = new DateInterval('PT1H');`

Answer (score 2):

You have a format issue with your `DateInterval` value and a syntax error as well:

```
<?php
$time = new DateTime();
$sub = new DateInterval('PT1H'); // <-- error #1
$time->add($sub);                // <-- error #2
echo $time->format('c');         // Here you can format your time
```

[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/mA41l)

Answer (score 0):

Try just running `strtotime` on the value stored in MySQL, then add `3600` to it and compare it to `time()` (you want to allow access if the modified value is less than `time()`)